# How to hide searchbar on another page

Tags: reactjs, hide, searchbar

I'am working on React.js Movie project and making few design changes like hiding SearchBar while navigating to another page.

Here are some js files for reference

1. Home.js

   ```
    <HeroImage
    image={`${IMAGE_BASE_URL}${BACKDROP_SIZE}${heroImage.backdrop_path}`}
    title={heroImage.original_title}
    text={heroImage.overview}/>
    <Header callback={this.searchItems}/>
    </div> : null }
    <div className="rmdb-home-grid">
    <FourColGrid
     header={searchTerm ? 'Search Result' : 'Popular Movies'}
    loading={loading}             >
    {movies.map( (element, i) => (
    <MovieThumb
    key={i}
    clickable={true}
    image={element.poster_path ? 
   `${IMAGE_BASE_URL}${POSTER_SIZE}${element.poster_path}` : 
   './images/no_image.jpg'}
     movieId={element.id}
    movieName={element.original_title}
       />
     ))}
   ```
2. App.js

   ```
   <React.Fragment>
       <Header />
       <Switch>
         <Route path="/" component={Home} exact />
         <Route path="/:movieId" component={Movie} exact />
         <Route component={NotFound} />
       </Switch>
   ```
3. Header.js {/* Code for SearchBar */}

   ```
    <div className="rmdb-searchbar">
    <div className="rmdb-searchbar-content">
    <input type="text" className="rmdb-searchbar-input"
    placeholder="Search..."
    onFocus={(e) => e.target.placeholder = " "} 
    onBlur={(e) => e.target.placeholder= "Search..."}
    onChange={this.doSearch}
    value={this.state.value} />
    <FontAwesome className="rmdb-fa-search circle icon" 
    name="search" size="2x"/>
    </div>
    </div>
   ```

Comment: Where did you use the `SearchBar` component?

Comment: I have used it in Header.js file... As you can see above className="rmdb-searchbar". I want to hide the search-bar when navigated to another page

Comment: Hi @Pranav did you have any luck integratng a solution?

Comment: Hello @ChristopherNgo I have done it by creating a completely different component and then calling it from main page and when navigated to other page the SearchBar disappears. Well thanks very much for helping

Answer (score 0):

few options for you,

you can use switch and choose in what route to show what component.
or you can use get your location from the props if you using react-router or from the document if not and then to do something like,

```
{ifIsTrue && <SearchBar />}
```

Answer (score 0):

Essentially you need your `Header` component to subscribe to updates OR update with new information about the `pathname` when the user navigates away from a page.

Use `withRouter` which comes from the react-router-dom library. This will pass updated props to the Header component, including information such as the new `pathname`.

Then you can extract that pathname via the props in `props.location.pathname`. With that data available to us, we can use conditional logic to determine on what pages we want to display your search-bar.

In our example below, we'll set it up so that we only display the search-bar when you are on the `Home` route.

**Header.js**

```
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom

const Header = (props) => {
    const location = props.location.pathname;
    const atHome = location === "/";

   return (
     <div>
        ...other markup
        {atHome && (
          <div className="rmdb-searchbar">
            <div className="rmdb-searchbar-content">
              <input
                 type="text"
                 className="rmdb-searchbar-input"
                 placeholder="Search..."
                 onFocus={e => (e.target.placeholder = " ")}
                 onBlur={e => (e.target.placeholder = "Search...")}
                 onChange={this.doSearch}
                 value={this.state.value}
              />
              <FontAwesome
                 className="rmdb-fa-search circle icon"
                 name="search"
                 size="2x"
               />
             </div>
           </div>
         )}

     </div>
   )
}

export default withRouter(Header)
```

I've replicated something similar in this codesandbox for your reference: https://codesandbox.io/s/using-withrouter-to-have-components-subscribe-to-routing-i9mt6